# How can I parse json date in tpl files?

Tags: php, json, format, smarty

My jSon date format:

```
release_date: "1426153440",
```

When I use like this, its done but has a format problem:

```
{$info.release_date}
```

Generate to:

```
1426153440
```

How can I solve format problem in tpl files? Thank you.

Comment: What format are you going for, need an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`date_format`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.date.format.tpl), with it you can combine the conversion specifiers available in [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php).

Example:

```
{$info.release_date|date_format:"%Y-%m-%d"}
```